# Positioning of Msal login popup

Tags: angular, typescript, popup, azure-ad-msal

I'm currently using the login popup from msal-angular to login to a Microsoft Office account for an Angular application. However, when the popup appears, it appears in the top left of the screen with half of the window off the screen. Therefore I have to resize it manually to get it to appear fully on screen.

Is there a way to change the positioning of this popup to appear in a certain position? E.g. in the middle of the browser window where it was called from?

My current popup call:

```
async signIn(): Promise<void> {
    const result = await this.msalService.loginPopup(OAuthSettings.scopes)
      .catch((reason) => {
        console.log('Login failed', JSON.stringify(reason, null, 2));
    });

    if (result) {
      this.authenticated = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or any demo to reproduce your error.

Comment: Could you not wrap force the login popup to be wrapped in a div and position it with css? or can you force the app `public offset: offset = { left: 100, top: 100 };`

Comment: @ScottChambers The popup is a new window though. CSS won't help position a window that's generated would it?

Comment: @NiallMitch14 if you can target the classes and they arn't randomly generated. IE there are unique "#ID's" or ".class" That are the same every time, then (IN THEORY) The css should be loaded. Then (IN THEORY) the generated window should position its self according the the overriding css style. Then it should style the window for you positioning it how you want. ie
`position: fixed !important; top: 50% !important; left: 50% !important; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: I see what you mean now. I noticed an iframe with id #msalRenewFrameuser.read.all being generated in the HTML but the css did nothing to change the position of the new window

Comment: @NiallMitch14 Sorry did you fix this?
Thats odd that the css didnt do anything? Even if it had "!important" on end?
Id assume there must be overriding css. although its dirty you could see if you could append the style to that div do EG:
`<div id="#msalRenewFrameuser.read.all" style="position: fixed !important; top: 50% !important; left: 50% !important; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">`

Also a good test. Make something blue or orange. :)

Comment: @ScottChambers I found that the iframe isn't pointing to the new popup window but is actually a small iframe window containing another instance of my website I'm working on. It had the css of visibility: hidden. Removing this and positioning the iframe to the center showed a small iframe of my website but did nothing to the popup from the MSAL popup. This is an entirely new window so I'm not sure if CSS is the answer to reposition this when it appears as it is technically not attached to the webpage...

Comment: @NiallMitch14 Oooof Iframe is big issue, its cross origin :/ there isnt much you can do on that front i'm afraid. unless you can link to their api and make your own login form?

Comment: Yeah I don't think such a small problem is worth the hassle... The login form appears fine in Edge but just slightly off screen on Chrome. Very weird issue. Thanks anyways @ScottChambers

Comment: As of MSAL 2.19.0 you can now pass a popupWindowAttributes.popupPosition(top: number, left: number) parameter in your loginPopup() request.  However, my initial testing shows that it still has no effect in Chrome.